# Calculate Rate based on distance range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, range

I have been working for a project which have the following table structure

```
start | end | rate
------------------
   1  |  50 | 10
  51  | 100 | 20
 101  | 150 | 40
 151  | 200 | 80
 201  |   0 |100
```

Here the last record means 200 to infinite value has the rate as 100

Here I have to calculate total rate based on the start and end values given by users

I have tried the following query in mysql for the input start - 30, end - 170

```
SELECT SUM((end+1 - start) * amount) 
FROM table 
WHERE start > 30
AND end < 170
```

which only gives 2nd 
and 3rd record values sum, then I have to query for first and last records separately.

How could I achieve this in single query?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that as the start goes up the rate go up so if you start at 30 and go to 170 then the math would be `(20*10)+(49*20)+(49*40)+(19*80)`?

Comment: Please share the actual formula to calculate the rate...

Comment: You are right, but with little bit correction, the math would be <pre>(20*10)+(50*20)+(50*40)+(20*80)</pre>

Comment: Depending on how your distance is calculated, you probably want to move to exclusive upper-bounds.  This is because there are values between 50 and 51 - see [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for timestamp-related examples.  In RDBMSs with recursive CTEs/a `ROW_NUMBER()` function, I'd only store the _start_ of the range, and essentially assemble this table as a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we have the following two parameters declared:

```
set @start = 30, @end = 170;
```

First to get the rows which fall within your range (overlapping), we would do ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de20ef/2)):

```
select start, end
from Table1
where start <= @end OR end >= @start
```

Then we massage the start and end of the ranges for the first and last rows. Basically we are capping the first part of the range at `@start` and the second part of the range at `@end` ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de20ef/4)):

```
select CASE WHEN @start > start THEN @start ELSE start END AS start, 
    CASE WHEN @end < end THEN @end ELSE end END AS end
from Table1
where start <= @end OR end >= @start
```

Then we can subtract these two case expressions to get the distance. And don't forget to add 1 if you want the *inclusive* distance ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de20ef/9)):

```
select CASE WHEN @end < end THEN @end ELSE end END - CASE WHEN @start > start THEN @start ELSE start END + 1 AS dist
from Table1
where start <= @end OR end >= @start
```

Multiply by rate. This time don't forget the parentheses, since multiplication takes precedence ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de20ef/10)):

```
select rate * (CASE WHEN @end < end THEN @end ELSE end END - CASE WHEN @start > start THEN @start ELSE start END + 1)
from Table1
where start <= @end OR end >= @start
```

And finally, slap a `SUM` around the whole expression to add it all up ([SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de20ef/11)):

```
select SUM(rate * (CASE WHEN @end < end THEN @end ELSE end END - CASE WHEN @start > start THEN @start ELSE start END))
from Table1
where start <= @end OR end >= @start
```

Comment: Instead of or condition in where clause we have to use and condition then have to check for end value 0 as infinite, start and end value may vary, if start - 230 and end 270 then the calculation should be 40*100=400

Comment: @Kanagu If you have any control over the data scheme, I suggest you to use `NULL` instead of `0` to identify infinity. You can then enforce a constraint `end >= start OR start IS NULL OR end IS NULL` and have the math all make sense with a few extra tweaks for `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on lc.'s algorithm, you can run this in MySQL:

```
SET @start = 30, @end = 170;

SELECT
  sum(rate * (least(`end`, @end) - greatest(start, @start) + 1)) TotalRate
FROM Table1
WHERE @end >= start OR @start <= `end`
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @lc Suggestion, the following query is suitable for my expectations

```
    SET @start=30, @end=170;
    SELECT SUM(rat*(CASE WHEN @end < end or end=0 THEN @end ELSE end END - CASE WHEN @start > start THEN @start ELSE start-1 END)) as price
    FROM rate
    WHERE start <= @end and (end >= @start or end=0)
```

and this query meets all the following criteria

when start-60, end-140 then the math would be `(40*20)+(40*40)=2400`

when start-230, end 270 then the math would be `(40*100)=400`